# Mutt macro weirdness

Tags: mutt

I have this in my `muttrc`:

```
macro index,pager a '<enter-command>set confirmappend=no delete=yes<enter>
   <tag-prefix><save-message>=Archive<enter><sync-mailbox><enter-command>
   set confirmappend=yes delete=ask-yes<enter>' "Archive"
```

which I got from somewhere.

Works fine at first. When I do an `A2`, which switches to my second account:

```
macro index,pager A2 '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.config/neomutt/mredaelli
   <enter><change-folder>!<enter><check-stats>'
```

it doesn't work anymore. What happens instead is that it tries to forward an email to `irmappend=yes@gimli, delete=ask-yes@gimli`, where gimli is my hostname. So basically it skips everything till `f` (I guess they are not bound), and then forwards.

But there's no binding command in the file (which is [here](https://github.com/mredaelli/dotfiles/blob/master/home/.config/neomutt/mredaelli)) that gets sourced: it's just a bunch of `set` and `mailbox` commands.

Also, if afterwards I re-source my `muttrc` without quitting, it works again.

Any idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I crafted a workaround which seems to do the trick for now. You mentioned you re-sourced the .muttrc file to fix the problem. So I added that command to the end of my own account switching macro.

**Original:**

```
macro index,pager <f4> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.mutt/account3<enter><change-folder>!<enter>
```

**Updated:**

```
macro index,pager <f4> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.mutt/account3<enter><change-folder>!<enter><enter-command>source ~/.muttrc<enter>'
```

You probably found your own solution by now, so I'll just leave this here for the next guy.

Answer (score 0):

For other people that face similar problem, I confirmed that re sourcing muttrc fixes the problem. 
But what I found is that removing `<sync-mailbox>` fixes the problem, so updated version looks like this

```
macro index,pager <f4> '<enter-command>source ~/.mutt/account3<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'
```